# SHA3 Function Properties

Tags: cryptography, sha

For

1. Theta
2. Rho
3. Pi
4. Chi
5. Iota

Do you know which provide permutation, non-linearity and substitution?
And how could I figure out if a function provides permutations/non-linearity/substitution.

Comment: I believe the site you want for this is crypto.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Do you know what "permutation" means? Or "non-linearity", or "substitution"?